# jquery scrolling function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this code to change position when scroll. The problem is when scrolled to top of the page css `top:'0px'` not working. 
Here is the code.

```
window.onload = function() {

    var stickySidebar = $('.bk-form-wrap').offset().top;
    var $div = $('div.bk-form-wrap');
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickySidebar) {
            $div.css({
                 position:'fixed',
                 height: '70px'
            });
            $div.animate({
                top: '95px',
                //top:'100%',
               // marginTop: - $div.height() 
            });
        }
        else {  
        }   

        if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
             //Call your event here
             $div.css({
                 position:'relative',
             });
             $div.animate({
                top:'0px',
             });
        }
    });
};
```

And link to [page](http://taruvillas.com.s207781.gridserver.com/V2/property.php?id=3). Plese help. Thanks.

Comment: You trying to change the position of what, when scrolled?

Comment: the booking form under the slider.

Comment: when scrolled to the top of page, '.bk-form-wrap' top should be 0

Comment: Could you describe what you want the form to do? Describe what you want to see, not what you want the code to do.

Comment: When you scrolled down the booking form should appear under navigation. This working fine. But when you scrolled to top of page the booking form should go to previous position.

Comment: It works for me with Firefox 43.0

Comment: it takes lot of time.

Comment: Obviously. If it worked for you, you wouldn't be asking here. What browser are you using?

Comment: After scrolled to top it takes about 15sec to  booking form to go to previous position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var $div = $('div.bk-form-wrap');  
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var stickySidebar = $('.bk-form-wrap').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickySidebar) {
         $div.css({
             position:'fixed',
             height: '70px'
              },1000);
        $div.animate({
            top: '95px'
            //top:'100%',
           // marginTop: - $div.height() 
        });
    }

    else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
       //Call your event here
         $div.css({
             position:'relative'
              });
           $div.animate({
            top: '0px'
        },500);
    }   
});
```